# How to import user's pki certificate into web page?

Tags: xpages

I have seen websites where users can click on a button to import their pki certificate into the web page.  I am looking for the same type of code.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a form with either a text field to enter the PKI cert, or a file upload of the PKI cert?

Comment: Sorry - did not explain in original request.  I need to get the PKI cert from the certificate that is in the user's browser,

Comment: Aha, I know that, depending on the browser, they usually use the native OS crypto functions. On Windows this is the CryptoAPI, on OSX it's the Keychain and I think Linux uses Mozilla NSS. I'm not sure if there's a nice JS library that wraps all of these into one call across all OS's but hopefully that'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  Yes - I hope there is one that can be used across all OS's.  I have been looking at the Java Class for X509Certificate.  But have not figured out how to get the certificate from the browser.

Comment: Have a look at the X509 client cert authentication spec. When you configure  to use that a standard API gets triggered